tar having much larger size than the containing files, can I make it smaller?
On Linux Mint 22, I created both GNU, and POSIX versions of tars containing 2 small files with:
$ tar --posix -cf archive-posix.tar auto-fan-control.cpp Makefile

$ tar         -cf   archive-gnu.tar auto-fan-control.cpp Makefile

$ file *.tar

archive-gnu.tar:   POSIX tar archive (GNU)
archive-posix.tar: POSIX tar archive


Surprisingly, the tars are equally of 10240 size while my files are much smaller:
$ \ls -l *.tar

-rw-rw-r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 10240 Dec 22 10:41 archive-gnu.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 10240 Dec 22 10:40 archive-posix.tar


$ \ls -l auto-fan-control.cpp Makefile 

-rw-rw-r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  863 Dec 22 01:10 auto-fan-control.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 1323 Dec 22 09:48 Makefile

i.e. my files are totalling just 2186 bytes, which in contrast to both tars that occupy 10240 bytes exactly, cannot be simply justified by including some metadata, like CRC and such. IMHO, there has to be some kind of padding if I called it correcly.
So, just to be clear, this question's answers DO NOT answer mine: A tar archive's size is larger than the size of the archived files

Thinking out loud, it appears the minimum size of tar is 10240, or its multiples, am I correct?
If I am right, just out of curiosity, is there anything I can do about it to make tar smaller?
Thank you.

tar was (is) a Tape ARchiver, and as a consequence writes data blocked for tape drives. (Tape drives require full blocks.)

@ChrisDavies Good to know. Thank you!

With GNU tar on Debian 12:
$ tar --show-defaults
--format=gnu -f- -b20 --quoting-style=escape --rmt-command=/usr/sbin/rmt --rsh-command=/usr/bin/rsh

Reading up on the -b option:

-b, --blocking-factor=BLOCKS
Set record size to BLOCKSx512 bytes.

So -b 20 would give you blocks of size 10240 bytes.  This is the minimal size of a GNU tar archive by default.  You may use -b to set a different block size, but the common way to make tar archives smaller is by compressing them with, e.g., gzip.
So, in effect, what you are seeing is padding.
See also the GNU tar manual: The Blocking Factor of an Archive.
